# import langchain works fine in a script but does not load in a juypter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, langchain

Ubuntu 22.04, Python 3.10.6

In my Juypter notebook, attempting to load langchain like this:

`import langchain`

gives me:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain'`

However, using a plain python script (like below) works fine.

```
import langchain
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor
print ("imports worked!")
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

This returns:

```
imports worked!
['/home/parallels/web/ChatGPT-Tabular-Data-main', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/parallels/web/ChatGPT-Tabular-Data-main/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

No trouble importing langchain.

So I go and check the paths inside Juypter like so:

```
import sys
import os
print(sys.path)
```

returns this:

```
path before adding langchain path
['/home/parallels/web/ChatGPT-Tabular-Data-main', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '', '/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

ok, so I see there's a langchain path appearing in my script output, let's add that to the Juypter path and also check which Python Juypter is running like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/parallels/web/ChatGPT-Tabular-Data-Main/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages')
print('\nand the new path is...')
print(sys.path)
print("let's see what python version jupyter is running")
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
```

returns this:

```
and the new path is...
['/home/parallels/web/ChatGPT-Tabular-Data-main', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '', '/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/home/parallels/web/ChatGPT-Tabular-Data-Main/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
let's see what python version jupyter is running
3.10.6
```

Ok, so got the right python, and the same path that works for the script is now in the path, but it is still not finding the module when I run that cell in Juypter.

Let's try this:

```
$ which langchain
/home/parallels/web/ChatGPT-Tabular-Data-main/env/bin/langchain
```

Let's add that to the path:

```
and the new path is...
['/home/parallels/web/ChatGPT-Tabular-Data-main', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '', '/home/parallels/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/home/parallels/web/ChatGPT-Tabular-Data-Main/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/home/parallels/web/ChatGPT-Tabular-Data-main/env/bin/langchain']
let's see what python version jupyter is running
3.10.6
```

... still ...

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain'`

I've also been restarting the Juypter kernel between tests so there isn't something old hanging around.

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to activate that environment at all? If so, install jupyter into that environment and use jupyter from there

Comment: Dang.  Goes to show how much one can forget when you're not doing much of it for months.  Sure enough:

'pip install notebook'

in the virtual environment and now it works fine.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be dead simple.

While it appeared that Juypter was running fine, it wasn't.  I had overlooked installing it in the virtual environment.

`pip install notebook`

...and now the notebook loads the library without complaint.